# escaping '.' and using a variable in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am a beginner when it comes to PL/SQL coding. I am trying to do some simple administrative work using PL/SQL. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
prompt Enter a value for the Schema that you just refreshed:
define owner=&1

BEGIN
    FOR x_rec IN (
        SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE owner='&&owner'
    )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''GRANT SELECT ON ' ||&&owner|| '.''||x_rec.table_name||'' to ' ||&&owner|| '_RO_ROLE'';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many quotes, for one thing. SQL*Plus uses a '`.`' to optionally terminate a substitution variable. If you want an actual dot as well, just use two.

Try this:

```
accept owner char prompt "Enter the name of the schema that you have just refreshed: "

begin
    for r in (
        select table_name from dba_tables where owner = upper('&&owner')
    )
    loop
       dbms_output.put_line('grant select on &&owner..' || r.table_name || ' to &&owner._ro_role');
       execute immediate 'grant select on &&owner..' || r.table_name || ' to &&owner._ro_role';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your help.